# Unable to find the documentation of TikZ/PGF 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, documentation, texdoc

After upgrading to the latest version of TikZ/PGF I cannot access, using `texdoc`, the newer version of the documentation. When I invoke `texdoc tikz` it tries to open the version that used to reside in:

```
~/Library/texmf/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf
```

(corresponding to `2.10CVS`). Somehow I cannot find a way to tell `texdoc` to open the right version which is located in:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf
```

A temporary workaround I use is to have a symbolic link from the former location to the latter. However, this is really ugly solution... I don't remember how I managed to tell `texdoc` to override the shipped documentation back when I manually installed the `CVS` version; thus I cannot simply undo it.

### Edit:

@AndrewSwann: The output of `texdoc -l tikz` is:

```
1 /Users/username/Library/texmf/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf
2 /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf
```

and the list go on... My question can be also stated: How can I remove `1` and make `2` the first one?

Comment: `texdoc -l` will list results and let you choose one

Comment: @egreg: If I do it, then `texdoc` complain that it cannot find the file at all.

Comment: Not the case for me :(
I remember I had to do something special to tell `texdoc` to open the 2.10CVS version of the doc (when I updated to it manually). But I cannot recall what was the process.

Comment: Same two lines as in the edit. Note that I changed the file that is merely a symlink.

Comment: @egreg: if file in $HOME is removed then `texdoc` doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, it still lists the wrong file at the first place, and doesn't reach the second place.

Comment: @egreg: did the trick! Don't I need `ls-R` for other stuff that I have in my local `texmf`?

Comment: @egreg: Do you want to summarize the comments into an answer, or should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *personal tree* rooted in `$TEXMFHOME` (`~/texmf/` on GNU/Linux systems, `~/Library/texmf/` on Mac OS X with MacTeX), should never have a `ls-R` file at the top; this is the setting of `TEXMF` in `texmf.cnf`:

```
TEXMF = {$TEXMFCONFIG,$TEXMFVAR,$TEXMFHOME,!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFLOCAL,!!$TEXMFDIST}
```

The absence of `!!` in front of `$TEXMFHOME` means that a `ls-R` file is not needed in the personal tree as well as in the “config” and ”var” secondary trees. However, creating it will make `kpathsea` use it.

In those trees one is supposed to have only a few things, so directly browsing the file system is not a costly operation. And it makes easier managing the personal tree, too, because you don't need `mktexlsr` after changing it.

So, remove `~/Library/texmf/ls-R` and be happy. Of course, remove (or rename) the old manual.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the CVS version of TikZ installed in your `$TEXMFHOME` (here,  `~/Library/texmf/`), you may use the following command (in a Terminal):

```
find ~/Library/texmf -iname pgf -exec rm -fr {} \; -print -prune
```